# Difference between "field of inquiry" and "field of endeavor"

Tags: differences, gre

These two kinds of phrase frequently pop out in the topics of GRE analytical writing. Is there any substantial difference in meaning?

EDIT:
I know the difference between the word "endeavor" and "inquiry", but can the "field of endeavor" and "field of inquiry" be used interchangably to some extent? For example, can the former include scientific research?

Comment: @Karsus, unfortunately, as this could have been looked up on the dictionary, it would be closed as "general reference" according to the faq.

Comment: OP: @Thursagen he is right: you can make this a much better question by looking up the definitions and finding some examples. Then if you have *further* questions, you can edit your question with the research you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of it in terms of venn-grams;  "field of endeavor" is a much broader descriptive of human activity, but it is one which includes "inquiry".   For instance, one can "endeavor" to excel through one's "inquiry" into the more esoteric scientific disciplines.  One can "endeavor" to cure cancer, as well, which would of course include several "fields of inquiry" -- medicine, biochemistry, etc.

Basically, "field of endeavor" describes a person's general psychological and spiritual comportment towards a range of activity, while "field of inquiry" describes a more particular range of activity ("inquiry");  or, in other words, "endeavor" describes why, or how one does something, while "inquiry" describes what.

Since "inquiry" can be an object of endeavor, it's clear the two can overlap.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they can be used interchangeably to some extent.

"Field of endeavor" sounds a bit broader and outward-looking to me, whereas "field of inquiry" could be seen as somewhat limiting by the subject under inquiry.

Yes, ["field of endeavor" can include scientific research](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22Field%20of%20endeavor%22%20%22scientific%20research%22).

Comment: I was asking whether field of endeavor includes scientific research. It sounds to me that field of inquiry is mainly scientific research.

Comment: The question asked from a user with reputation 152 has been answered from a user with reputation 1952.